# SQL - Count number of rows based on date and when next three columns are same

Tags: sql-server, date, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to create a report.  In this query I have four columns being selected

- Date - yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss format
- ID - A six int number
- GroupNumber - Single character int
- Type - Single character

I need to count how many rows exist where the date is different but the ID, GroupNumber, Type are the same.  The date doesn't necessarily need to be displayed

Here is the code I have so far

```
    Select DISTINCT CAST(MeasureDate AS Date) AS MeasureDate,
    StudyNumber, GroupNumber, [Type]
    From tUserEquipMeas

    Group by StudyNumber, MeasureDate, GroupNumber, [type]
```

Comment: so the row number returned from that query is the number you want?

Comment: I need to return how many rows come back where the date is different but the other three values are the same.  For example, if there are three dates in yyyy-mm-dd format but the studyNumber, groupNumber, type are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the distinct /  unique count.

```
select count(*) from (
select 
    count(distinct cast(MeasureDate as date)) as CT,
    StudyNumber, 
    GroupNumber, 
    [Type]
from tUserEquipMeas
group by
    StudyNumber, 
    GroupNumber, 
    [Type])
```

Comment: Unfortunately I will need to cast the date in just yyyy/mm/dd format.  I do not care too much about the time, but the date is what is important.

Comment: no worries, you can cast that inside as i did above.

Comment: I am receiving a syntax error on the last parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

count of date?

```
Select count(MeasureDate) AS MeasureDateCount,
StudyNumber, GroupNumber, [Type]
From tUserEquipMeas

Group by StudyNumber, GroupNumber, [type]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I will need to cast the date in just yyyy/mm/dd format.  I do not care too much about the time, but the date is what is important.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to include some sample data and expected result based on that data.  Because it is unclear for example if you want the count only for each combination of SudyNumber, GroupNumber, and Type or if you want the distinct count of days for each of combination and then the aggregate count of that.  Also it is not clear if you want any details on the combination.

@scsimon has a good answer if you simply want the overall count of all unique combinations of StudyNumber, GroupNumber, Type, And Date.

If you simply want the count with the combination your query could be modified as follows:

```
Select COUNT( DISTINCT CAST(MeasureDate AS Date)) AS CountOfDistinctMeasureDates,
StudyNumber, GroupNumber, [Type]
From tUserEquipMeas
Group by StudyNumber, MeasureDate, GroupNumber, [type]
```

And if you want the details of each combination with the overall count all in the same query because you tagged a sql-server capable of using window functions here is one way:

```
SELECT
    CAST(MeasureDate AS DATE)
    ,Studeynumber
    ,GroupNumber
    ,Type
    ,COUNT(*) as NumberOfTotalRecordsInGroup
    ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Studeynumber, GroupNumber, Type) AS NumberOfDistinctMeasureDatesForGroup
FROM
    @Table
GROUP BY
    CAST(MeasureDate AS DATE)
    ,Studeynumber
    ,GroupNumber
    ,Type
```

Here is some test data for you:

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (MeasureDate DATETIME, Studeynumber INT, GroupNumber INT, Type CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO @Table (MeasureDate, Studeynumber, GroupNumber, Type)
VALUES
    (GETDATE(), 123456, 1, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE()), 123456, 1, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,GETDATE()), 123456, 1, 'A')
    ,(GETDATE() - 1, 123456, 1, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE() - 1), 123456, 1, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,GETDATE() - 1), 123456, 1, 'A')
    ,(GETDATE() - 2, 123456, 1, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE() - 2), 123456, 1, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,GETDATE() - 2), 123456, 1, 'A')
    ,(GETDATE(), 123456, 2, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE()), 123456, 2, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,GETDATE()), 123456, 2, 'A')
    ,(GETDATE() - 1, 123456, 2, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE() - 1), 123456, 2, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,GETDATE() - 1), 123456, 2, 'A')
    ,(GETDATE() - 2, 123456, 2, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(MINUTE,-2,GETDATE() - 2), 123456, 2, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(MINUTE,-3,GETDATE() - 2), 123456, 2, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(MINUTE,-4,GETDATE() - 2), 123456, 2, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(MINUTE,-5,GETDATE() - 2), 123456, 2, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(MINUTE,-6,GETDATE() - 2), 123456, 2, 'A')
    ,(GETDATE() - 3, 123456, 2, 'A')
    ,(GETDATE(), 123456, 1, 'B')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE()), 123456, 1, 'B')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,GETDATE()), 123456, 1, 'B')
    ,(GETDATE() - 1, 123456, 1, 'B')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE() - 1), 123456, 1, 'B')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,GETDATE() - 1), 123456, 1, 'B')
    ,(GETDATE() - 2, 123456, 1, 'B')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE() - 2), 123456, 1, 'B')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,GETDATE() - 2), 123456, 1, 'B')
    ,(GETDATE(), 789012, 1, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE()), 789012, 1, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,GETDATE()), 789012, 1, 'A')
    ,(GETDATE() - 1, 789012, 1, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE() - 1), 789012, 1, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,GETDATE() - 1), 789012, 1, 'A')
    ,(GETDATE() - 2, 123456, 1, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-2,GETDATE() - 2), 789012, 1, 'A')
    ,(DATEADD(HOUR,-4,GETDATE() - 2), 789012, 1, 'A')
```